# En una estructura de control If - Else if - Else, ¿puedo meter un bucle for para cada condicionante?

Tags: java, bucle-for, condiciones, try-catch

estoy realizando un pequeño proyecto para ir familiarizandome con JAVA y tengo esta duda.

A continuación detallo un poco la duda:

Dispongo de un try-catch, con un if-elseif-else dentro y un bucle for después del else

```
  try {
      if {}
      else if {}
      else {}
      for {}
   }catch {}
```

¿Sería válido meter un bucle for en el IF y otro bucle for para el ELSE IF?

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: *Sería válido?* Si lo que necesitas hacer funciona así, si. Por qué no?? Las estructuras de control de flujo (if, elseif, else, for...) están para que tú las uses como veas conveniente. Cómo las uses, dependerá de las necesidades de lo que quieres hacer. Como no sé exactamente qué estás haciendo, es imposible que te responda *si, así es la mejor manera* o *no, hazlo de esta otra manera* porque literalmente, ***NO SABEMOS QUÉ INTENTAS HACER***.

Comment: Por lo que has puesto en el código, sí. Java es secuencial, y va ejecutando sentencias de una en una. En tu caso, si no hace el if,  pasa al else-if, y por último, si no, al else. Y, cuando pase eso, si no ha tirado ninguna excepción, pasará al for.

Comment: Ahora bien, si ambos bucles van a hacer exactamente lo mismo... no, no sería *válido*, estaría correcto, pero estarías repitiendo código innecesariamente. En ese caso deberías extraer el bucle a un método y llamar al método en donde lo necesites, pasándole los parámetros correspondientes.

Comment: Hola, lo primero muchas gracias por las respuestas y la rapidez. Por otra parte, como estoy comenzando puede ser que no haya aportado toda la información necesaria. Yo quería expresar que si cumple la condición del IF, realice un bucle recogiendo unos valores determinados y si cumple la condición de elseif, realice un bucle con esos valores + x. Gracias.

Comment: Depende de lo que quieras hacer, todo es valido y son condiciones, si se cumple entra sino no.

Comment: Hola, como te dijeron mas arriba en los comentarios. Por favor agrega un problema específico en tu pregunta, de otra forma podría ser cerrada por falta de detalles. Puedes editar tu pregunta para poder agregar mas detalles y un problema específico. Te recomiendo que hagas el recorrido del sitio https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para aprender como funciona

Answer (score 0):

Según la definición de "válido":

> Que tiene valor legal o capacidad para producir el efecto que se espera.

La respuesta es si, es válido meter un bucle for dentro de un bucle if, un if else y un else. Ya que el bucle for se va a ejecutar según el flujo del programa ingrese en uno u otro bloque condicional.

Solo para aclarar, si bien entiendo que el código que pusiste en tu pregunta es para ayudar a entender tu duda:

```java
  try {
      if {}
      else if {}
      else {}
      for {}
   }catch {}
```

A los condicionales les falta la condicion:

```java
  try {
      if(condicion1) {
        for(int i = 0; i < algo; i++){
         ...
        }
      }
      else if(condicion2) {
        for(int i = 0; i < algo; i++){
         ...
        }
      }
      else {
        for(int i = 0; i < algo; i++){
         ...
        }
      }
   }
   catch(Exception ex) {
     ...
   }
```

PD: Si tu pregunta iba por otro lado, por favor editala y agrega mas informacion y detalles